# How to fix "Reference Error : function is not defined" error in Typescript

Tags: typescript

**I am new to angular. I want to use pignose calendar in my application. So, I add it as javascript, when selecting the date I need to call a backend service. I don't know how to call a service from the jquery library.**

```
$('.timetable').pignoseCalendar({
            select: function (date, context) {
                var dt = date[0];
                var myDate = new Date(dt);
                var selectDt = myDate.getUTCFullYear() + '-' + (myDate.getUTCMonth() + 1) + "-" + (myDate.getDate());

this.timetableservice.getTimetabledate(selectDt).pipe(
            takeUntil(this.unsubscribe),
            finalize(() => {
                this.loading = false;
                this.cdr.detectChanges();
            })
        ).subscribe(x => {
            if (x.rstat == "S") {
                this.outputData = x.rdata;
            }
        },
            err => console.error('Timetable Observer got an error: ' + err));               
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because of the dynamic evaluation nature of `this` reference in Javascript, you are passing an object to `pignoseCalendar` with a key `select` whose value is a function, and inside that function, you are passing a function reference, `this.unsubscribe` to `takeUntil`, the problem here is that you are creating this function value for the key `select` with the `function` keyword, so when this function is executed, it needs to be executed in some parent scope, which is the global scope because that function is not bound to any object, and `this` reference will always point to the object that the function is bound to, which will be `window` by default when the function is not bound. To make `this` point to the current class instance, you need to use an arrow function, and don't just pass `this.unsubscribe` to `takeUntil` because `this.unsubscribe` will be evaluated in a different scope, and if it makes use of `this` inside, then `this` will point to something else rather your current class instance unless you bind it to the current class instance, the overall fixes will be like this

```
$('.timetable').pignoseCalendar({ 
  select: (date, context) => {  // Here
    var dt = date[0]; 
    var myDate = new Date(dt); 
    var selectDt = myDate.getUTCFullYear() + '-' + (myDate.getUTCMonth() + 1) + "-" + (myDate.getDate()); 
    this.timetableservice.getTimetabledate(selectDt)
      .pipe(
         takeUntil(() => this.unsubscribe()), // And here
         finalize(() => { 
           this.loading = false;
           this.cdr.detectChanges();
         })
      )
      .
      .
      .
```